# Order of normalizer in $S_6$

Tags: group-theory

Find order of normalizer of permutation $s= (12)(34) \in S_6.$

I tried it and I thought we need all permutations $p$ s.t $psp^{-1}=s,$ I wrote down such $p,$ I counted $8.$ But in book answer is $16$.

Comment: I'm guessing you've probably not realised that the permutation $(1,3)(2,4)$ centralizes $s$. Does that help?

Comment: Also, the idea of a *normalizer* is usually reserved for subgroups. I'm guessing you really mean *centralizer*.

Comment: Nick what do u mean by centralizes s.? Whats this concept

Comment: $$C_G(s)=\{x\in G:sx=xs\}.$$

Comment: Foggy, the set Ofir has defined above is the *centralizer in $G$ of $s$* - an element is said to *centralize* $s$ if it lies i this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $S_6$ acting on itself by conjugation.
Now, what is the size of the conjugation class of $(12)(34)$?
So what does it tell you about the size of the normiaizor of this element?

I will follow my advice. A simple combinatorial arrgument show that there are 
$$\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}}{2}=45,$$
elements of the form $(ab)(cd)$ is $S_6$ and they are all conjugate.
Then, by the orbit-stabilizer theorem the normilaizor (cenralizer) is of order 
$$\frac{720}{45}=16.$$